# DataContext SubmitChanges

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ-to-SQL. I have retrieved an Entity called FileType using FileTypeID from the respository. Now I have created an entity called ExportFile. ExportFile is a child of FileType.

so here is what I have done:

```
var itemType = Repository.Current.ItemRepository.GetItemTypeByID(100);
```

Now I create a ExportFile Entity as follows:

```
var exportItem = new Item() { GroupNumber = "000" };
itemType.Add(exportItem);
```

And then I do the following:

```
Repository.Current.SubmitAllChanges();
```

Now my question is: should ExportFile be added to the database or do we need to use the add entity of the dataContext explictly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DomainRepositoryManager.Current.SubmitAllChanges(); would be good to save the changes in the database.